# Rock, Paper, Scissors wont execute past the first block of code

Tags: python

```py
import random
import sys

print('Rock, Paper, Scissor')

#These variables keep track of the number of wins, losses, and ties.
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0

while True:
    print('%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Ties' % (wins, losses, ties))
    while True:
        print('Enter your move: (r)ock, (p)aper, (s)issorcs, or (q)uit.')
        playerMove = input()
        if playerMove == 'q':
            sys.exit()
        if playerMove == 'r' or playerMove == 'p' or playerMove == 's':
            break
        print('Type one of r, p, s, or q.')

        if playerMove == 'r':
            print('Rock versus...')
        elif playerMove == 's':
            print('Scissors versus...')
        elif playerMove == 'p':
            print('Paper versus...')

        randomNumber = random.randint(1,3)
        if randomNumber == 1:
            computerMove = 'r'
            print('Rock')
        elif randomNumber == 2:
            computerMove = 'p'
            print('Paper')
        elif randomNumber == 3:
            computerMove = 's'
            print('Scissors')

        if playerMove == computerMove:
            print('Wow! It is a tie!')
            ties = ties + 1
        elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 's':
            print('Rock smashes Scissors! You win!!!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 'r':
            print('Paper smothers Rock! You win!!!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'p':
            print('Scissors slice Paper! You win!!!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'r':
            print('Rock smashes Scissors! You lose!!!')
            lossess = losses + 1
        elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 'p':
            print('Paper smothers Rock! You lose!!!')
            lossess = losses + 1
        elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 's':
            print('Scissors slice Paper! You lose!!!')
            lossess = losses + 1
```

When I run this in PyCharm it accepts my inputs(the r,s,p,or q) but doesn't move forward with the game. The only input that works correctly is q. That leads me to think I don't have the *break* in my while-Loop correct, but it also is not returning any errors so I don't know what's up.

Apricate any help or hints you all can give me.

Comment: Why do you break out of the inner while loop if `playerMove` is r p or s? All your "valid" inputs result in a break or `sys.exit()`

Comment: I thought that I would have to break the user out of the loop. I was trying to setup a loop inside of a loop. The first loop is the main game and the second one is asking for the player input. Once the player makes a choice they break out of the ''choice'' loop and into the ''game'' loop until the game ends. The only input that ends in sys.exit() is q. Which, if you run it in Pycharm, is the only input that works

Comment: Your indentation is off.  Your game logic should not be inside the innermost `while` loop because that loop's sole job is to fetch the input until the user inputs something valid.

Comment: while True:
    print('%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Ties' % (wins, losses, ties))
    while True:   #is this the the innermost loop?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your indentation proper by making all the code after `print('Type one of r, p, s, or q.')` outside of the inner while loop.
Also, check the variable "losses".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is breaking loop everytime in

```
if playerMove == 'r' or playerMove == 'p' or playerMove == 's':
            break
```

try like this

```
import random
import sys

print('Rock, Paper, Scissor')

#These variables keep track of the number of wins, losses, and ties.
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0

while True:
    print('%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Ties' % (wins, losses, ties))
    while True:
        print('Enter your move: (r)ock, (p)aper, (s)issorcs, or (q)uit.')
        playerMove = input()
        if playerMove == 'q':
            sys.exit()
        print('Type one of r, p, s, or q.')

        if playerMove == 'r':
            print('Rock versus...')
        elif playerMove == 's':
            print('Scissors versus...')
        elif playerMove == 'p':
            print('Paper versus...')

        randomNumber = random.randint(1,3)
        if randomNumber == 1:
            computerMove = 'r'
            print('Rock')
        elif randomNumber == 2:
            computerMove = 'p'
            print('Paper')
        elif randomNumber == 3:
            computerMove = 's'
            print('Scissors')

        if playerMove == computerMove:
            print('Wow! It is a tie!')
            ties = ties + 1
        elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 's':
            print('Rock smashes Scissors! You win!!!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 'r':
            print('Paper smothers Rock! You win!!!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'p':
            print('Scissors slice Paper! You win!!!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'r':
            print('Rock smashes Scissors! You lose!!!')
            lossess = losses + 1
        elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 'p':
            print('Paper smothers Rock! You lose!!!')
            lossess = losses + 1
        elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 's':
            print('Scissors slice Paper! You lose!!!')
            lossess = losses + 1
        if playerMove == 'r' or playerMove == 'p' or playerMove == 's':
            break
```